# Qt Widgets expanding not working when using widget container

Tags: qt, widget, containers, expand

I have a widget container (further *QWidgetsContainer*) with custom widget implementation (further *QAdvanceWidget*) with custom controls. I try to make  *QAdvanceWidget* expanding, when it puts into QWidgetsContainer, but something wrong.

*QAdvanceWidget* code:

```
/** Advance widget with some controls */
class QAdvanceWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    /** Constructor */
    QAdvanceWidget(QWidget *poCustomWidget = 0)
    {
        QHBoxLayout *poLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
        poLayout->setSpacing(0);
        poLayout->setMargin(0);
        this->setLayout(poLayout);
        this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        // Adding custom widget if need
        if (poCustomWidget)
        {
            poCustomWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
            poLayout->addWidget(poCustomWidget);
        }

        // Controls

        // Button for deleting widget
        QPushButton *poButtonDelete = new QPushButton();
        poButtonDelete->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
        poButtonDelete->setText("Delete");
        poLayout->addWidget(poButtonDelete);
        // button connect

        // Button with some functionality
        QPushButton *poOtherButton = new QPushButton();
        poOtherButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
        poOtherButton->setText("Other");
        poLayout->addWidget(poOtherButton);
        // button connect

    }

    /** Custom widget getter */
    QWidget *poCustomWidget()
    {
        return _poCustomWidget;
    }

private:
    /** Custom widget */
    QWidget *_poCustomWidget;
};
```

*QWidgetsContainer* code:

```
/** Advance widgets container */
class QWidgetsContainer : public QWidget
{
public:
    /** Constructor */
    QWidgetsContainer()
    {
        QVBoxLayout *poLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
        poLayout->setSpacing(0);
        poLayout->setMargin(0);
        this->setLayout(poLayout);
        this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    }

    /** Create advance widget */
    QAdvanceWidget *poCreate(QWidget *poCustomWidget = 0)
    {
        QAdvanceWidget *poAdvanceWidget = 0;
        QVBoxLayout *poLayout = qobject_cast<QVBoxLayout*>(this->layout());

        if (poLayout)
        {
            poAdvanceWidget = new QAdvanceWidget(poCustomWidget);
            _oListAdvanceWidgets.append(poAdvanceWidget);
            poLayout->addWidget(poAdvanceWidget, 0, Qt::AlignBottom);
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "QWidgetsContainer poCreate - Layout nullptr error";
        }

        return poAdvanceWidget;
    }

private:
    QList<QAdvanceWidget*> _oListAdvanceWidgets;
};
```

Using code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QWidgetsContainer *poWidgetsContainer = new QWidgetsContainer();
    this->setCentralWidget(poWidgetsContainer);

    QPushButton *poTestButton = new QPushButton();
    poTestButton->setText("Test button");

    QListView *poTestListView1 = new QListView();
    QListView *poTestListView2 = new QListView();



    poWidgetsContainer->poCreate(poTestButton);     // Add widget with custom widget ( PushButton )
    poWidgetsContainer->poCreate(poTestListView1);  // Add widget with custom widget ( ListView 1 )
    poWidgetsContainer->poCreate();                 // Add widget with empty custom widget
    poWidgetsContainer->poCreate(poTestListView2);  // Add widget with custom widget ( ListView 2 )
}
```

And as a result we can see:
[Result image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd7VE.png)

I want full expanding my widgets (without spaces). What am I doing wrong? And what I have to do to solve my problem?

Comment: I think you're trying to get individual layouts to do too much work.  Try removing *all* calls to `QWidget::setSizePolicy` and change `poLayout->addWidget(poAdvanceWidget, 0, Qt::AlignBottom)` in `QWidgetsContainer::poCreate` to simply `poLayout->addWidget(poAdvanceWidget)`.  How close does that get you to what you need?

Comment: Maximally close. Big Thanks!! It works! I thought that Qt::AlignBottom need for adding as the last down element in the vertical layout (and Qt::AlignTop for adding as first up element). But for this insertWidget method exists. Big thanks again!